# Install asp.net session state database on SQL Server query

Tags: asp.net-mvc

We have a mvc4 .net app to be deployed in a Win2008 64bit server and required to use SQL Server sessionState. The .net framework ver is 4.5

The asp.net session state db is to be installed in another server, which has .net framework 2.0. Must the .net framework 4.5 be installed in this server to run the `aspnet_regsql.exe` command (since the web app is of .net 4.5)? Or can .net 2.0 `aspnet_regsql.exe` be used for installing the asp.net session state db?

Many Thanks,
Ben

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple way to check this. Run .NET 2.0 on your machine and check if the DB schema is same.

But much better idea is to use -S switch to run asp_regsql from your IIS server like this:

```
aspnet_regsql.exe -S YourSqlServer
```

-S means:

> Specifies the name of the computer running SQL Server where the
>   database will be installed, or is already installed.

More options are on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229862(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: But will a 4.0 app work on the database created by 2.0 aspnet_regsql?